# Python : Why does False or 'name' returns 'name' and not False?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

AFAIK :

`and`, `or` are boolean operators and any boolean expression should return a boolean.

So, why does this happens :

- `False or 'name'` returns `'name'` and not `True`
- `True and ''` returns `''` and not `False`

Please explain, how does python handles boolean expressions ?

Comment: Downvoter, please at least share what could have been improved ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in python the `or` and `and` operations short circuit and return the last evaluated item.

See [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

If you *must* have a boolean value, use [`bool()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool):

```
>>> bool(False or 'name')
True
```

Comment: But when i tried it in javascript and ruby, it worked same as in python. But when I tried same short circuit in C it returned 1 and 0, i.e. boolean results. Since we are using cpython it should behave same as C, but its is not. Why?

Comment: This is python, not C. It's the same in Jython, PyPy and IronPython. The language specifies this is how it works, and the 'side effect' is used in many places; e.g. `somevariable = someothervariable or fallback`.

Comment: I didn't mean that it is fight between languages, I mean that 'and' and 'or' are logical operators, so they should return a boolean result, by default.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: But why 'should' they? Note that before python 2.2, there were no booleans values in Python, only boolean interpretations of standard types (`0`, `0.0`, `''`, `[]`, `()`, `{}` are all considered False, most other things are True). The short-circuiting nature of these operators is an incredibly useful feature, and I emphatically do *not* agree that they should return a boolean just because they operate on boolean principles.

Comment: @Martijin, Ok I got you, what you wrote earlier was right, :).